# Is that possible to display timestamp in a shorter format in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

By default, my `psql` shows `2018-03-10 23:06:09.970888+08` in select outputs. Is that possible to display the timestamp in a shorter format? This is too long and make the display is very ugly. Something like `180310 23:06:09.97` is fine to me.

Btw, I don't want to use `\x auto` or change my select query (such as `select to_char(...) from`). I am wondering if there is a global config way to handle this situation.

### Edited

I found a workaround. Put `\pset format wrapped` to my `~/.psqlrc`. It will make the output much nicer and wrap the output to screen width. I am OK with this setup for now.

Comment: If you found a solution, then please add that as an answer. Otherwise this question will remain unsolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Put `\pset format wrapped` to my `~/.psqlrc`. It will make the output much nicer and wrap the output to screen width. I am OK with this setup for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options (ISO, SQL, Postgres, or German) for date/time output, but they are not exactly what you want:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But none of the options can make the display shorter..